# Compressed Air Spaceship

Tags: propulsion, travel

Imagine a people who live within the debris ring of a planet.  They make their homes on rocks that are only dozens of miles in diameter, so escape velocity is not a concern.  They also do not need to travel very far: when orbital alignment is favorable, two rocks might be as close as 20,000 miles.

Unfortunately, the primary means of propulsion used by these people is compressed air.  **How big do these ships need to be to get from one rock to another?**

Ideally, the journey should not take longer than 2 days.

I tried to work this out myself using the rocket equation but my smooth brain can't figure it out.

**Specs**

- For the tanks of air, consider [this commercial product](https://www.compressorworld.com/400-gallon-vertical-air-tank.html).  It seems to weigh about 700 lbs empty, has a capacity of 400 gallons and is rated for 165 psi.  One way of answering "how big" this ship needs to be would be to indicate how many of these tanks would be needed to make a 20,000 mile journey in 2 day.
- The payload is a cabin for two humans that weighs 2000 lbs.

Comment: This question may get better answers in world building stack exchange, to maximise the chance of getting answers useful to you suggest looking at solar sails and either using them, or specifically excluding them to get answers about cold gas rocket ISP.

Comment: What's important is not how far apart they are, but what the difference in their orbital distance is. They're likely to spend more propellant avoiding debris than performing the transfer.

Comment: Can you edit your question to demonstrate that it has any relevance to real world space exploration? Or is it a purely fictional scenario?

Comment: @GremlinWranger  That stack can be great for some things, but they have a habit of ignoring the actual question and instead answering what they think the true question is.  I very specifically want to know about traveling with compressed air: on WorldBuilding, I'd get a dozen answers suggesting alternative means of propulsion (like solar sails).

Comment: @OrganicMarble  I was unaware that "real world space exploration" was a requirement of this stack.  I was unable to find a community guidelines page.

Comment: Here's the "what's on topic" page. https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @OrganicMarble  Thank you! It is my understanding that this question satisfies at least two of the on-topic items.  I do not see "fictional space exploration" on the list of off-topic subjects, and in fact there seem to be many answered questions on this stack that fall into the same bucket.  Please let me know if you feel my question needs more information.

Comment: Should fit well in the "Trajectory design, orbital and celestial mechanics" category, but could need some editing to make that clear.

Comment: Question is fine here, voting to **leave open** so as not to quickly deny all users any opportunity to post orbital-mechanical answers. It's not like we have too many questions per day and need to aggressively cull questions that "might be" off topic via insta-close technology. Let's see how the answers unfold!

Comment: @uhoh how, exactly, are you *voting to leave open*? No close votes have been cast.

Comment: @OrganicMarble how? *preemptively* of course! :-)

Comment: @uhoh must be an owner's privilege :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble well closings can come quickly and I may be "away from my desk" this weekend depending on the weather, so I thought I'd add my two cents while I had the opportunity.

Comment: Lots more information must be supplied to answer the question as asked **How big do these ships need to be**.  What is the mass of the payload to be delivered? (meaning everything in the ship but propellant) How highly compressed can the air in the ship's tanks be? (higher pressure means smaller tanks but stronger ones)  What level of thrust do you envisage?  What kind of structural technology does your fictional civilization have?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you for helping me improve my question.  I have added some additional information.

Comment: Getting there!! That seems a horrible structure fraction for an aerospace tank though. Consider a COPV. Also the link does not work, so I could not get the deets.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Oops, sorry about the link!  I understand there are better ways to get around space - this is a question about very low tech though. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @PinkSweetener clarify please - is the compressed air tank to supply atmosphere and breathable oxygen to the cabin as well ?  Or is that a separate supply?  Wasting breathable air on propulsion feels like a waste.  Can you allow any compressed gas instead or does it have to be air ?

Comment: @Criggie  Apologies, I missed your comment.  Unfortunately, compressed air is all they've got!  Do not worry about life support, I can figure that part out on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited to remove a maths error in using the rocket equation**

This is a [cold gas thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_gas_thruster), so theoretical [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse) of around 80 (breathing air being mostly nitrogen). Using the [rocket equation](http://quantumg.net/rocketeq.html). If we assume 10% of the craft mass is compressed air this gives 82ms budget for maneuvering, if we make 90% of the mass propellant this goes up to 1805ms. While simple to design and safe to this is why real world cold gas systems only show up where very low DV is acceptable, since it does not take much performance improvement from an ISP of 80 to justify extra equipment mass in the rocket hardware.

20000 miles in two days stops being orbital dynamics and becomes a brute force [torch ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchship) profile. A straight line trip of 20000 miles in two days needs a velocity of 833 miles and hour or 372 m/s (and we want to stop so twice that), our 10% gas craft only has 78.4 total ms velocity, so not good enough, going to 60% makes it possible for a one way trip.

In practice it is not the distance that matters but the velocity difference in orbits. For earth moving from 500 to 1000km up (LEO) by definition objects will regularly be less than 500km apart, but if they [hohmann transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit) they will do the maneuver closer to opposition and travel half an orbit to close the distance, but do so efficiently. Looking at something [like](https://www.satsig.net/orbit-research/delta-v-geo-injection-calculator.htm) tells us a total DV of 260ms and around an hour. This is beyond the capability of a 10% by mass craft but a 30% one could do it. if out around lunar orbit (not not near the a moon) at 300,00km then a 500km orbit change involves less than a meter of DV, and a 12 day trip so very possible with pretty much any thrust system, as long as the 12 day timeline was acceptable. If more fuel available then the time can be reduced, potentially back to the straight line approximation where two 100ms 'burns' (25% gas by weight) do the trip in around an hour and a half.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer!  I'm not sure why you are insisting on a craft that is only 10% gas though.  It is my impression that most spacecraft are 80%+ fuel.

Ion drives are beyond the scope, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: This covers all the important points, but the "95% gas" part does not appear to be quite right. An Isp of 80s and a mass ratio of 20:1 is an overkill delta-v budget of 2350m/s. The mass ratio for a 372m/s budget is a much more reasonable 1.6:1, less than half the mass of the ship being propellant.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys yep, I've badly goofed the mass ration conversion.

Comment: Then I can safely go to sleep trusting everything will be in order when I wake up.

Comment: @PinkSweetener, the 10% was based around this craft being something useful for trading/moving cargo/making return trips, may have misunderstood the question. It also makes the maths easier since per the interaction with SE you start needing more than just google and a calculator when you go into high mass fractions.

Comment: @PinkSweetener spacecraft that are 80% propellant don't carry their main propellant in the form of a gas. Gases have very low density, increasing that density involves increasing their pressure and using heavier tanks to store them. Outside of certain special cases, it's much more practical to store liquid propellants.

Comment: I note that this does not answer the question that was asked **How big do these ships need to be** but of course enough information to answer that was not provided.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff  I understand that, but it's outside the scope of this thought experiment.  If you think the answer to my question is "compressed air travel within the range you suggest is impossible" then I would appreciate it if you wrote that up as an answer.  Obviously I am not asking "is compressed air better than liquid/solid fuel rockets?"

Comment: @OrganicMarble  I did in fact update the question with the requested information.  Regardless, I am very thankful for this answer.